# Simulation framework

Tags: hardware, simulation

I am working on embedded software for an industrial System. The system consists of several stepper-motors, sensors, cameras, etc. Currently, the mechanics as well as the electronics are not available - only specification.

I've implemented the simulation for some parts of mechanics/elektronics, but it takes a consiredable amount of efort. So my question:

Are there good portable (Win/Linux) Hardware simulation frameworks? Easy to install/use and affordable in prise?
My basic requirements are:

- Send command to stepper  -get interrupt from light-barrier
- recognize object with camera ( not necessary)
- mechanical parts should move according to steppers but stop
  on obstacles.
- objects should fall, if there is no ground underneath
- fluids should increase/decrease volume in bassins according to
  physical laws

My Application is in C++/Qt, so it would be the best, if such a framework had C/C++ bindings.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem as I have to develop systems to interface with several types of automation devices (robots, firmware devices, etc). I still want to provide unit test for my code, but after writing 3 or 4 simulated devices, I thought it got to be a better way.

Fortunately in my case, my code was all in C# and the final solution was to use Moq to create simple mocks of those devices. I'm not familiar with mocking frameworks for C++/Qt, but a simple [search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=mocking%20for%20c%2b%2b&src=ie9tr) rendered a couple of results, including one made by google (googlemock).